# Redux saga value cannot apply or use immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Redux store cannot use immediately.

***Backgound:***

I have created a parent component and a child component.

The parent component will fetch a list of data, save to redux store,and generate child component.

example:

```
result:[
  {
    key: 1,
    roomNo: '01',
    status: 'OCCUPIED',
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    roomNo: '02',
    status: 'UNOCCUPIED',
  },
]
```

Then, there will be 2 child component (which is a button). And if I click the child button. The application will call DB again for more detail and save to redux store also.

```
detailResult: [
  {
    key: 1,
    roomNo: '01',
    status: 'OCCUPIED',
    roomColor: 'red',
  },
]
```

And since I would like to check whether the status is the same (result.roomNo="01"(**OCCUPIED**) and detailResult.roomNo="01"(**OCCUPIED**) ) (to ensure the data is the most updated one when user click the button)

Therefore, I write the following function in child component:

```
const { reduxStore } = useSelector((state) => ({
        reduxStore : state.reduxStore ,
    }));

const retrieve = useCallback(
            (params) => {
                dispatch(Actions.wardFetchRoom(params));
            },
            [dispatch]
        );
    
    const handleClick = (event) => {
            const params = { roomNo: roomNo};
            retrieve(params);
            console.log('Step1', props.bedNo);
            console.log('Step2', props.status);
            console.log('Step3', reduxStore.room.status);
            //function to match props.status === reduxStore.room.status
        };
```

The problem comes when I click the the child button. The data always compare with previous store data but not current store data

```
T0: render finish
T1: click <child room="1"> 
T2: console: "Step1 = 1, Step2 = OCCUPIED, Step3 = NULL" (I expect "Step3 = OCCUPIED",since retrieve(params) is completed and the store should be updated at this moment)
T3: click <child room="2"> 
T4: console: "Step1 = 2, Step2 = UNOCCUPIED, Step3 = OCCUPIED" (This "Step3" data is come from T2, the data is delay for 1 user action)
```

Therefore, how can I change my code to use the store data immediately?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the code that you've posted.  It's possible that you are mutating the store state instead of returning a new object.  The component won't re-render after the `dispatch` if the state was mutated.

Comment: I have tried to add a break point in my backend code, and find that the app execute Step 1-3 before the retrieve function finished. Is there anyway to make sure that only execute Step 1-3 after retrieve function is finished?